# Convert compiled armv7 static library to arm64?

Tags: ios, linker, static-libraries, static-linking, arm64

My iOS app uses a static library (*.a) from a vendor which no longer exists. I do not have the source code and cannot recompile the library for arm64.

The problem is that Apple is now requiring apps to contain an arm64 slice.

How can I use this armv7 static library in my app? Can I somehow convert the .a from armv7 to arm64?

Comment: There is no way to do this.

Comment: Not possible. Your will have to find a new vendor or library. Who is it?

Comment: @JERC nope I don't think there is one

Comment: @Keith you got any proceedings over this?